# Column Stacking & Inventory Numbering In Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Long time lurker. I can't quite get this right. I'm attempting to Repeat Column 1 x many times based on multiple columns of integers in Google Sheets.

This is the formula I am using.

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT(text(A1:A4,"0")&""&"|",TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B1:D4,B1:B4>0)&"-"))),"-"))),"|",1,1)),"Select * WHERE Col1 Is Not Null"))
```

It repeats column A B1:B4 times but does not continue through C&D.

[image: Google Sheets Sample]

[Link To Google Sheet Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qurtQPubb233Hk5EjVLhCwbn7ttM-qjqu-3rqplGqak/edit?usp=sharing)

Any guidance? I've got to be close...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One more approach:

```
=tocol(map(tocol(index(if(B:D,A:A,)),1,1),tocol(B:D,1,1),lambda(Λ,Σ,wraprows(Λ,Σ,Λ))),3)
```

[image]

Comment: This works fantastic, thank you! It even handles blank cells. You saved me HOURS. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Try the following formula-

```
=TOCOL(BYROW(TOCOL(INDEX(BYCOL(B1:D4,LAMBDA(cl,REPT(A1:A4&"|",cl)))),1,1),LAMBDA(rw,SPLIT(rw,"|"))),1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",1,ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REPT(A1:B4&";",B1:B4),";")),ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REPT(A1:B4&";",C1:C4),";")),ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REPT(A1:B4&";",D1:D4),";"))),","))
```

**Result:**
[image]

**Explanation:**

Using the `ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REPT(A1:B4&";",B1:B4),";"))` to repeat the ColA n number of times from ColB. Apply the same formula to the columns C and D. Then using `TEXTJOIN()` and `SPLIT()` to make it output in 1 row.